# How to pass media stream from angular code to Facemesh.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

How can i replace this camera function and pass my own mediastream from another angular module?
Src: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh

```
const camera = new Camera(videoElement, {
  onFrame: async () => {
    await faceMesh.send({image: videoElement});
  },
  width: 1280,
  height: 720
});
camera.start();
```

I am unable to pass mediastream to faceMesh.send() if i try to remove camera fucntion.

Comment: replace the camera function and pass your own MediaStream to faceMesh.send()

Comment: if i'm try to pass my own mediastream in facemesh.send() than i get error

Answer (score 0):

**MediaPipe FaceMesh** can read `HTMLVideoElement` (behind the scenes its just a copy-frame-to-canvas followed by get pixels from canvas to tensor), so you don't have to deal with that.

But your media stream will not have per-frame events (there is no such thing in JS specs) - that's what `Camera` wrapper value-add is.

Not going to write the code for you, but workflow you need is:

1. do `faceMesh.send`
2. listen for results
3. once you have results do next `faceMesh.send`